# ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css

Tags: angular

I want to install materialize-css, jQuery and font-awesome, in my Angular 8 project, I'm running this cmd:

```
npm install materialize-css jquery make-awesome --save
```

and I add the link in `angular.json`:

```
 "styles": [
              "Src / styles.css"
              "Node_modules / materialize-css / dist / css / materialize.css"
              "Node_modules / font-awesome / css / font-awsome.min.css
            ]
 "scripts": [
              "Node_modules / jquery / dist / jquery.js"
              "Node_modules / materialize-css / dist / js / materialize.js"
            ]
```

knowing that **angular-cli.json** file does not exist in my project, I get this error:

> ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css.

and when I change the links to:

```
"./Node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css"
 "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awsome.min.css
```

I also get an error.

Also for

```
"../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css",
"../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awsome.min.css
```

This is the error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D: \ node_modules \ jquery \ dist \ jquery.js'

Comment: Have you checked that jquery.js exists in the given folder?

Comment: @maio290 yes jquery.js exists in root node_modules / jquery / dist, there are also core.js files, jquery.js jquery.min.js ..

Comment: Why your path having / with a space in between ?

Comment: And why is "node_modules" written as "Node_modules"?

Comment: @TonyNgo no is jist in have space here but in my projet is not have

Comment: @tenkmilan but my file name is node_modules

Comment: Yes, your folder should be named  "node_modules" with lowercase at the beginning. But you wrote in your path "Node_modules" with upper case.

Answer (score 0):

For the CSS part following may help:

Try to remove the materialize-css and font-awesome entries from the "styles" in `angular.json` and try to add them to the beginning of the `styles.css` following way:

```
@import "~../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css";
@import "~../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
```